# SQL-Запрос к вложенным json в поле

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, запрос

Postgre. В поле data находится json следующего  вида:

```
{"verify": null, "full_name": "sequence", "classes": {"9999": {"id": 11226, "title": "approval"}}}
```

Мне необходимо обратится конкретно к значению ключа classes которое одновременно является и  ключом (9999).
Пробовал такой запрос

```
select * from advertising where data->>'classes' = '{"9999"';
```

но результата не дало.

Добавлю. Запрос будет использоваться  в коде и '9999' будет заменено на переменную.

Comment: data->'classes'->>'9999' так доступ осуществляется

Comment: я ж показал как будет выглядеть запрос. При чем здесь, то что вы написали?

Comment: select data->'classes'->>'[тут значение переменной]' as d from advertising

Comment: json_extract_path и аналогичные позволяют собрать требуемый путь выражением. А уж что может jsonb_path_query_array...

Comment: @Виктор а вот это уже интереснее. Только не пойму почему выдача идёт двух записей, одна пустая и одна с данными

Comment: @Stieglits может у Вас в базе не одна запись с "classes"  : { "9999"

Comment: @Виктор тогда бы она не была пустой

Comment: Чего гадать, вы глазками посмотрите по таблице (надеюсь она не большая:)

Comment: @Виктор в итоге я сам запутался и всех запутал. Мне надо вытащить все поля из таблицы, а я вытаскиваю просто поле с джсоном. а мне нужно в where поместить конкретный элемент select data->'classes'->>'[тут значение переменной]'

Comment: @Stieglits ну и как, получилось?

Comment: @Виктор да, ответ добавил, теперь то, что нужно тянется. Дичь конечно такие жсоны в базу пихать.-_-

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом получил нужные записи из таблицы.

```
$db->query("select * from advertising where data->'classes'->'" . $classId . "'->>'id' = '".$classId."';")->fetchAll();
```